# OpenVAS - Not able to download report after scan

Tags: openvas

OpenVAS Version:  OpenVAS 9 Community Edition,  Greenbone OS 4.1.7

I am using OpenVAS appliance installed in Hyper-V virtual machine.

I have scanned my network and got the results. I'am able to view the scan results, but I couldn't download the report in any format (like PDF, XML etc).
There is no option to select the format also. It shows, No results found.

Screen shot attached.
[image: OpenVAS - No results found for format]

Comment: i  have downloaded the CentOS and then installed OpenVAS, in which I am able to download the reports in required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GSM Community Edition was released in a new version 4.2 and now includes the report formats again as [announced](http://lists.wald.intevation.org/pipermail/openvas-announce/2018-February/000213.html):

> One noteworthy bugfix: In GCE 4.1 the report plugins were missing and now are back.

Disclaimer: Answer of a NVT Developer @ Greenbone

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this one out as I too had the same issue. You need to import the report types. However the link to import them no longer works. As far as i can tell this version of OpenVAS does not support exporting of reports.
I have since downloaded a VM of KaliLinux and installed Openvas in there. this works perfectly and includes exportable reports!

Comment: I have downloaded the CentOS and then installed OpenVAS, in which I am able to download the reports in required format.

Answer (score -1):

For version 7 of openvas just go to the configuration tab and Alerts.
Create a new alert
Once the window is open, scroll down and you will find the drop-down list with the different export format.

If export does not work, download the missing package with the yum command.

Comment: Hi, welcome. [Stack Overflow is an English-only website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/3082296)